How i can decompile Frida JS script, that was compiled by frida-compile?
I have a Frida JS script that I compiled into bytecode using frida-compile. I know that this process is reversible since it should be possible to return the code to its original state (or something close).
I've tried using some sourcemap extractors, but they didn’t work as expected.
How can I reverse the compiled Frida bytecode back into its readable JS source code?
Here’s a preview of my script for context: My script preview
Any guidance or tools to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
